# My code skips the IF block and goes to ELSE

Tags: python

Just started python a few hours ago and stumbles across a problem.
The blow snippet shows that initially I store a userInput as 1 or 2 then execute a if block. Issue is that the code jumps straight to else (even if i type 1 in the console window). 
I know Im making a simple mistake but any help will be appreciated.

using Python 3.5 === running in Visual Studio 2015 === specifically cPython

```
userInput = float(input("Choose 1 (calculator) or 2 (area check)\n"))
if(userInput =='1') :
    shape = input("Please enter name of shape you would like to calculate the area for\n")

if(shape == 'triangle') :
    base = int(input("Please enter length of BASE\n"))
    height = int(input("Please enter HEIGHT\n"))
    print("The area of the triangle is %f" % ((base * height)*0.5))

elif (shape == 'circle') :
    radius = int(input("Please enter RADIUS\n"))
    print("The Area of the circle is %f" % ((radius**2)*22/7))

elif (shape == 'square') :
    length = int(input("Please Enter LENGTH\n"))
    print("The area of the square is %f" % ((length**2)*4))

else :
    initial1 = float(input("Please enter a number\n"))
    sign1 = input("please enter either +,-,*,/ \nwhen you wish to exit please type exit\n")
    initial2 = float(input("Please enter number 2\n"))
if(sign1 == '+') :
    answer = float(initial1) + float(initial2)
    print(answer)
elif(sign1 == '*') :
    answer = float(initial1) * float(initial2)
    print(answer)
elif(sign1 == '-') :
    answer = float(initial1) - float(initial2)
    print(answer)
elif(sign1 == '/') :
    answer = float(initial1) / float(initial2)
    print(answer)
```

PS. if [possible] could you keep the help as basic as possible as I wanna make sure i understand the basics perfectly.

Thanks for all the help!! :D

Comment: you are converting to a float but comparing against a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are converting your input to float but checking for the string of the number. Change it to:

```
If userInput == 1.0:
```

Or better yet, keep it the way it is and just don't convert your user input to float in the first place. It is only necessary to convert the input to `float` or `int` if you want to do math on it. In your case you are just using it as an option, so you can keep it as a string:

```
userInput = input("Choose 1 (calculator) or 2 (area check)\n")
```

P.S. make sure to be very careful with indentation in Python. I assume your indentation is correct in your code editor, but also take care when pasting into this site.  You have everything on the same level here, but some of your `if` blocks will need to be indented further in order for your program to work properly.

Comment: Thanks you so much @elethan - Worked perfectly. Ill stick with removing `float` as it makes more sense.